# C++ openssl: editing ciphersuites

Tags: c++, openssl

I have very basic C++ application that uses openssl library.
Application sends request to server and the list of ciphersuites have to be the next:

**4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53**

(Codes of ciphersuites can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.tlsciphersuite?view=net-5.0)

But when I am setting ciphersuites in application manually it looks this way:

**4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-52393-49196-49200-159-52393-52392-52394-49195-49199-158-49188-49192-107-49187-49191-103-49162-49172-57-49161-49171-51-157-156-61-60-53-47-255**

I am trying to set ciphersuites this way:
`SSL_set_ciphersuites(ssl, "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256");`

So the question is: **How to remove exact ciphersuites from list of  ciphersuites ?**

Was trying to use ! and - as described here (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html)
`SSL_set_ciphersuites(ssl, "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:-TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256");`

But no luck.

**UPDATE:**

Using SSL_set_cipher_list before SSL_set_ciphersuites helped me. But now I have another problem:
When I use next list:**TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA**

I am getting **4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53-255**
But I cannot understand where **255** in the end come from ? It shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to the [man3 SSL_set_ciphersuites](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_set_ciphersuites.html) the cipher suits TLS_ECDHE_* in your list are not valid for the function.

> Valid TLSv1.3 ciphersuite names are:
>
> TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
> TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256
> TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256

2. Are you sure the server you are trying to connect use TLSv1.3 and not TLSv1.2, and you should also use SSL_set_cipher_list() with SSL_set_ciphersuites().

Comment: thank you so much! But now I have another problem. Just updated the question..

Comment: If you have another question, it is better to accept the answer and post a new question on SO. Otherwise your original post can be closed as containing multiple questions.